# Option 'basePath' must be a directory Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have this code and it's giving the error basepath must be a dir. Just want to run a simple streaming kafkaSink.

```
val checkPointDir = "/tmp/offsets/" // "hdfs://hdfscluster/user/yarn/tmp/"

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
            lazy val spark = SparkSession
              .builder
              .appName("KafkaProducer")
              .master("local[*]")
              .getOrCreate()



           val query = writeStream(jsonDF, "test")
            query.awaitTermination()
          }


      def writeStream(df:DataFrame, topic:String): StreamingQuery = {
    //    log.warn("Writing to kafka")
        df
          //      .selectExpr( "CAST(value AS STRING)")
          .writeStream
          .format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaServers)
          .option("topic", topic)
          .option("checkpointLocation", checkPointDir)
          .outputMode(OutputMode.Update)
          .start()
      }
```

My user is the owner of this folder /tmp/offsets. I'm getting this exception.

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Option 'basePath' must be a directory**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Option 'basePath' must be a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48357753/error-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-option-basepath-must-be-a-directory)

Comment: Nope! I've already tried that. Its different from that.

Comment: can you try providing canonical path of the file like this `new File(path).getCanonicalFile`

Comment: which file? the one I make dataframe from? 
Im using a local file and read the file using spark.readStream.text(PATH_TO_FILE)
and getCanonicalPath also returns the same path .

Comment: /home/user/Documents/fn/Proto2/src/main/resource/events-identification-carrier-a.txt
its like this

Comment: Oh got it! Fixed it! yes, i was giving the file name as well.
But now I have a question why we only need to give the path to the DIR and not specify the filename? What if there are multiple files in the same Dir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"checkpointLocation"` should be given a canonical path of a directory.

This directory is used to store the actual intermediate RDDs. There can be more than one RDD stored given there are multiple checkpoints. Each RDD's data is stored in a separate directory. However, RDDs themselves are partitioned, each partition is stored in a separate file inside the RDD directory. When storing files in HDFS, Spark has to abide by the max block size property. Storing such structured data is not possible in a single file, hence directory.